# How to generate xml for use with geoxml3

Tags: shapefile, javascript, kml, convert, xml

I have a kml and shp I would like to convert to an xml to use with geoxml3. How would I go about doing such a thing? The xml I generate should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"     xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<name>Districts</name>
<Style>
    <ListStyle>
        <listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType>
        <bgColor>00ffffff</bgColor>
        <maxSnippetLines>2</maxSnippetLines>
    </ListStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="trb655">
    <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<font font size='3' color="#aa0000"><b>$[name]</b></font>
              <table border='1' padding='1'>$[description]</table>                  
              <br><a href='http://shape2earth.com'><b>Shape2Earth</b></a>]]></text>
    </BalloonStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff84685b</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>ff13e69b</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="trb71">
    <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<font font size='3' color="#aa0000"><b>$[name]</b></font>
              <table border='1' padding='1'>$[description]</table>                  
              <br><a href='http://shape2earth.com'><b>Shape2Earth</b></a>]]></text>
    </BalloonStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff84685b</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>ffeaed3b</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="trb470">
```

The "Polystyle" and "BalloonStyle"; what can generate this with a shapefile or kml as a ref?

Answer (score 1):

The geoxml3 library works with KML (which is just a variant of XML, anyway), so there is no need to "convert [your KML] to an XML." If you have Shapefiles you wan t to convert to KML files, you can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" example.kml example.shp
```

You can generate KML programmatically in Python using [PyKML](http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/).